# How can I implement Google One tap login in react native apps?

Tags: npm, react-native, google-one-tap

I want to implement Google one-tap login in one of my react native applications. How can I do this? I assume I will need to use some existing library to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean sign in with google ? Have you try this package [google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin) ?

```
import { GoogleSignin, statusCodes } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import LoginButtonBase from './LoginButtonBase';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';


class GoogleLoginButton extends LoginButtonBase {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // GoogleSignin.configure({
        //  offlineAccess: true,
        //  webClientId: "your-client-id"
        // });
    }

    async login() {
        console.log('login google');
        try {

            let hasGoogleService = await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
            if (!hasGoogleService) {
                Alert.alert(null, "This device has no google play");
                return;
            }
            await GoogleSignin.signOut();
            const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
            let { idToken } = userInfo;
            if (idToken) {
                this.props.dispatch({
                    type: "auth/googleLogin",
                    payload: {
                        googleToken: idToken
                    }
                })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error);
            if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
                // user cancelled the login flow
            } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
                // operation (e.g. sign in) is in progress already
            } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
                // play services not available or outdated
            } else {
                // some other error happened
            }
        }
    }
}

export default connect(null, null)(GoogleLoginButton);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. The code above is for generic sign in with google. Last year Google released a new auth flow named as Google One Tap for android. Basically One tap automatically shows a pop up of google accounts being used.

Comment: Have a look at it. https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android